# Is there a CSS selector for an IMG which has been constrained by max-width or max-height?

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I define the following CSS rule:

```
img {
    max-width:  200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Is there a pure-CSS way of detecting those image objects that would have been larger without the size constraints?  Something that semantically matches:

```
img:resized {
    border-color: green;
}
```

---

Alternatively: is there a way of only detecting large images in the first place?  For example:

```
img {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
img[width>200px], img[height>200px] {
    max-width:  200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    border-color: green;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: 2017, any new update?

Comment: @dklt I doubt it -- the point in the accepted answer (that CSS selectors are based on the DOM, and CSS doesn't alter the DOM) hasn't changed.

Comment: thx for update ~ I ended up using img[src*=mySubFolderPath] {...} as a workaround.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there are no CSS selectors that can query style properties, whether declared or computed, as rendering of DOM elements has no relation to the DOM hierarchy.

Comment: Why did this answer get marked down? It is the correct answer.

Comment: Huh, at least I explain my downvotes, unlike someone else, whoever it is. I don't give a crap though; I'm Alt+Tabbing between SO and a TF2 Dodgeball game so whatever.

Comment: @BoltClock: *Is* someone targeting you and your beloved [css-selectors]? It looks coincidental. Your "why downvote" comments are longer than your answer :o

Comment: @thirtydot: I'll never know, and I don't usually respond to downvotes anymore — but this particular one was situationally amusing to the point that I just *had* to write something ;)