# How to styling img with varied size?

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a CSS selector for an IMG which has been constrained by max-width or max-height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143242/is-there-a-css-selector-for-an-img-which-has-been-constrained-by-max-width-or-ma)

In my page, I have some images with varied size. 
**All images no class nor id attributes.**

I want to do:

If image is larger than 680px, its border color is #aaa

If image is smaller than 100px, it has no border;

etc..

Is there any way to do this? 
Is there any pseudo or selector for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CSS cannot read the size of images. You need to use JavaScript to do this.

Comment: Hey BC: that one was still in your head :)